# delphi; animation composed of 2 layers with transparency

Tags: delphi, graphics, video, multimedia

I need to display an animation, composed of 2 layers with alpha transparency. I need this so I can decide and show the right combination on the fly.

- We can use png sequences, videos with alpha, or anything else.
- The animation is short, 8 secs, 15 fps, 320x120 pixels, no audio.

It's not feasible to pre-render each combination, because we have 2 layers, 100 variations each, which need to blend over a fixed static background; that would need 100x100 = 10000 sequences.

So; is it possible to composite 2 animated layers in Delphi, without too much synch loss?

Duck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a 3rd party graphics library such as [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/wiki/). You'd build each frame into an in memory bitmap and then blit it to the screen. Achieving flicker free 15fps at 320x120 would be easy – I reckon you could get more than 10 times the frame rate with some ease.

On the other hand I don't think it would be too hard to just draw it onto a TPaintBox with plain GDI commands.

Answer (score 1):

let it in two Panels. And use GDI+ to let the Panels have transparency. Or you can use RaizeComponents's RzPanel, it has alpha attribute.

Comment: It's a little hard to see how either of these approaches would give you sufficient control of the ordering of the drawing.